# Selenium - Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to web scrape the list of restaurants from a website using Selenium, but I always get the error NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id="lista-encontrada"]/div[2]/div[1]/h4"}

I've searched for similar errors but it's always related to frame or iframe, but I can't seem to find them in this particular website. Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.restaurantemadero.com.br/pt/restaurante/sp/sao-paulo'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

restaurants = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('blocos')

nome_loja = restaurants[0].find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="lista-encontrada"]/div[7]/div[1]/h4')
```

Any hint will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `restaurant name` use following xpath. `//div[@class='blocos']//h4`

Following code will returns `restaurant name` in a list

value using **text:**

```
print([res.text for res in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='blocos']//h4")])
```

OR
value using **textContent:**

```
print([res.get_attribute("textContent") for res in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='blocos']//h4")])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, KunduK! I'm still trying to figure out what you've done, but it worked! So thanks again!